# How to Push Two Interconnected Images or a Yaml File to Docker Hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I'm an absolute beginner to docker hub and am trying to push two images to docker hub. One image is a MySQL database the other is a java war running on tomcat. The second image is an MVC application that links to the first.

I have tried searching for a solution without success.

Thank you,

Wex

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stock `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for the database; don't try to roll your own database container.  Build a custom image (probably based on the [stock `tomcat` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat)) and push that to Docker Hub.  Add the `Dockerfile` you used to build the image and the `docker-compose.yml` that drives the combined application to the root of your repository, next to your `pom.xml` file, and check them in to source control.

There's no way to push a Docker Compose YAML file or a "combination of multiple images" to Docker Hub in any form, only individual images, so those need to be stored separately.